# Custom WordPress Registration Page <select>

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically I have a custom registration page which is being displayed on the front-end of my WordPress install, I'm using the [Cimy User Extra Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/) plugin to add a drop down `<select>` input to the form.

I need a way to manually hardcode this input directly in my registration page template.

If anyone has any idea on how to achieve this I would really appreciate it.
Cheers,
Tom.

Comment: That's a terribly coded plugin. Check if Advanced Custom Fields does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin lacks the frontend functions needed to display input elements.
Don't try to look for the internal functions building the inputs, they are way too tied to WordPress admin internal code.

As a quick&dirty fix I basically copy-pasted the generated HTML from the administration form to my public page template. You'll notice that it prepends `cimy_uef_` to field names. 
Then I used [update_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) in a [user_register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) hook and saved/added the value to `wp_usermeta`.

This goes into `functions.php` in your template or a custom plugin:

```
add_action('user_register', 'my_registration_save');

function my_registration_save($user_id) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['cimy_uef_some_field_name'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'cimy_uef_some_field_name', $_POST['cimy_uef_some_field_name']);    
}
```

Next you'll have to add your input to the custom registration template and give it `name="cimy_uef_some_field_name"`. You can basically go to admin/users, click on one of them to get to the edit form and copy the HTML generated there by CIMY for the field you need.

Also have a look in the `wp_usermeta` table and see if it does or does not strip the `cimy_uef_` prefix when saving fields, then change the second parameter in `update_user_meta` accordingly.

Comment: Yeah I just tried this actually, couldn't get it to save the values unfortunately, if you're feeling extra helpful would you mind showing me exactly how you got the values to save and update? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to drop the plugin altogether, I didn't need it. I just followed this:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50125/drop-down-list-in-user-profile-page

Thanks to anyone who tried to help. You are awesome.